# Отслеживание трафика по ip между двумя устройствами C#

Tags: c#, сеть, трафик

Пишу свою программу для мониторинга.
Мне необходимо узнать ip адрес отправителя/получателя, время отправки/получения и размер данных пакета, который передаётся от одного устройства к другому.

Comment: Отличие от [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1567027/220553) вопроса в чем? Не плодите дубликатов, пожалуйста. Есть доп. информация - кнопка "править" под вопросом, редактируете, готово. Хотите привлечь больше внимания - проявляйте активность под вопросом, а когда накопите репутацию, начните "Конкурс". Но не дубликат...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Операционная система какая?